# What's the meaning ? (Auf jeden Fall werde ich ihn dafür bezahlen: morgen geht er einkaufen.)

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This is from video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3upy1XbVjsQ
In 11:50, the sister complains about her brother.

```
Auf jeden Fall werde ich ihn dafür bezahlen: morgen geht er einkaufen.
```

it is translated into :

```
In any case, I will pay him for it: tomorrow he goes shopping.
```

I can't understand the exact meaning. Can anybody give me some explanation?

Comment: it is 'ihn'. now I realized what the meaning was in the context. I'll answer my question myself.

Comment: The colon doesn't make sense, I think it should be a dot. You're asking for the exact meaning, but missed to tell us, what you think, what the rough meaning is. Maybe that's as exact as it gets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check your source more carefully. In your video around the 11:50 mark, you can clearly see that the sentence should be:

> Auf jeden Fall werde ich ihn dafür bezahlen **lassen**: morgen geht er einkaufen!

The *lassen* is integral to the understanding of this text. Literally, this could be translated as *I will let him pay for that*. But in this specific context, it should be *I will make him pay for that*.

Comment: ah, that was correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I realized what the meaning is from the context. The statement should be translated as below :

> In any case, I will make him pay for it (I'll get even): tomorrow, he goes shopping.

(she complains mother always makes him just relax while she makes her(sister) do the chores. The sister wants her brother to do the chores tomorrow)

Comment: I still find it odd. Usually, one would either say: "Ich werde ihn dafür bezahlen **lassen**" or "**Er wird** dafür bezahlen" to express "I'll make him pay".